# Modify filename using java

Tags: java, file

I'm Parsing filename and password,Now i need to modify Filename and return modified filename.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{
   public static String renameFile(String fileName, String password)
           throws IOException {
       String new_name="modified";
       File oldFile = new File(fileName);
       File newFile = new File(new_name);

       if(oldFile.renameTo(newFile)){
           return newFile.getName();
       }
       return null;

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       System.out.println(renameFile("C:\\Users\\RSk\\Desktop\\NAR.pdf","none"));
   }

}
```

But i can't able to proceed more further than this.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a `File` object with the old name first, and then rename that to `new_name`. You can't call `renameTo` on a string.

Comment: You're not using the password; why are you mentioning it?

Comment: @ernest_k i'm new to java ,just learning

Answer (score 2):

1st Create a `File Object` of file with old name and then rename it, Try this:

```
public static String renameFile(String fileName, String password) {
        String prefix = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1); //path of file
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".")); //extension
        String new_name= prefix+"modified"+extension;
        File oldFile = new File(fileName);
        File newFile = new File(new_name);  //you cannot use string to rename so you need to create a file object with that new name

        if(oldFile.renameTo(newFile)){
            return newFile.getName();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

USAGE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter file name");
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter password");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println(renameFile(fileName,password));

}
```

**P.S:** You will also need to make sure, that `new_name` should be the correct path (where you want the file) as well, else it will be moved to default folder with renaming

> **[renameTo() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo-java.io.File-)**

Comment: i'm getting Null as output,i've updated ,my code @Mustanhsan

Comment: how can i do this by taking inputs from user?Sorry i'm totally new to java. Learning java and simultaneously working on it

Comment: what do you want as input

Comment: filename and password as input. and also i've updated my code in question im getting null as output.

Comment: @saiKrishnakingdom i have updated my answer please check both methods

Comment: i'm still getting null as output

Comment: file is being renamed and you getting null output?

Comment: file is not getting renamed.I'm using intellij on console im getting null as output

Comment: what are you passing as input?

Comment: First im parsing filename,Which is in same directory where program is.Then the password

Comment: im parsing pdf file and im getting null as output